# Argument ngrams not used

Tags: r, quanteda

I use quanteda for text analysis

I use this commands

```
corp_df2 <- 
    tokens(df$text,
           remove_punct = TRUE, 
           remove_numbers = TRUE, 
           remove_symbols = TRUE) %>%
    tokens_remove(pattern = stopwords(source = "smart")) %>%
      tokens_wordstem()

corp_df3 <- dfm(corp_df2) %>%
    dfm_trim(min_termfreq = 0.95, termfreq_type = "quantile") 

myDfm <- dfm(corp_df3, ngrams = c(1,3))
```

But I receive this error

> Argument ngrams not used.

How can I use the command to receive ngrams?

Comment: Can you make this question reproducible by adding example input and expected output ?

Comment: You need to form ngrams from the tokens object, not from the dfm object. Features (columns) from a dfm have no ordering and therefore you cannot form ngrams from a dfm object.